# Barrier implementation in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I've implemented a barreir in C++ close to one showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27118537/1690777). In the project code it's used only with two threads and seems to work. A synthetic test didn't expose any flaws too. But I suspect that on some machines it segfaults and/or falls through `wait()` call.
How do you think, can it fall through `wait` or is any race scenario possible with it?
Used mainly on Windows machines, if it matters.

```
class Barrier
{
public:
    explicit Barrier(uint16_t iCount) : maxThreads(iCount), count(iCount) {}

    void wait(std::chrono::milliseconds = std::chrono::milliseconds(0));

private:
    void notifyAll();

private:
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    uint16_t maxThreads;
    uint16_t count;
    bool generation = true;
};

inline void Barrier::wait(const std::chrono::milliseconds timeWait)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ulock(mutex);
    auto gen = generation;
    const auto waitCondition = [this, gen]{ return (gen != generation); };
    if (0 == --count) notifyAll();
    else {
        if (timeWait == std::chrono::milliseconds(0)) cv.wait(ulock, waitCondition);
        else {
            const auto timedOut = !cv.wait_for(ulock, timeWait, waitCondition);
            if (timedOut) ++count;
        }
    }
}

inline void Barrier::notifyAll()
{
    generation = !generation;
    count = maxThreads;
    cv.notify_all();
}
```

P.S. I know that `generation` is poor naming for this particular variable. Here it's intended to express similarity to the same name variable from abovementioned SO question code.

Answer (score 6):

Naming nitpicks: The relationship between `count` and `maxThreads` is not obvious. I would probably name them something like `threads_arrived_` and `total_threads_` (using the common convention of postfix-underscore for data members).

You might like to know that there's a [`std::barrier`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/barrier) in C++20. Your `wait` is what C++20 calls `arrive_and_wait`.  Your `generation` is what C++20 calls the "phase."

---

Why is your `notifyAll` a separate function, given that it's private and called only in a single place? You should just inline it. As a bonus, you could then *drop the mutex lock* before calling `cv.notify_all()` — this is widely quoted as a performance optimization.

---

You wrote:

```
void wait(std::chrono::milliseconds = std::chrono::milliseconds(0));
```

Being as [default arguments are the devil](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/04/18/default-function-arguments-are-the-devil/), this is a red flag. Personally I would write this as

```
void arrive_and_wait();
void arrive_and_wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds timeout);
```

and continue adding an `arrive_and_wait_until` as well. I would *not* use overloading or default arguments to accomplish this, because "wait for 0 milliseconds" and "wait forever" are *completely different things*. You really really don't want someone doing, like,

```
barrier.wait(user_configured_timeout);      // wait for 1ms
barrier.wait(user_configured_timeout / 2);  // wait for half that
```

and getting an infinite wait instead. Follow the STL's lead here: `wait`, `wait_for`, and `wait_until` are all different operations.

---

```
if (0 == --count) notifyAll();
else {
    if (timeWait == std::chrono::milliseconds(0)) cv.wait(ulock, waitCondition);
    else {
        const auto timedOut = !cv.wait_for(ulock, timeWait, waitCondition);
        if (timedOut) ++count;
    }
}
```

This is a ridiculously misindented piece of code. Try this:

```
if (0 == --count) {
    notifyAll();
} else if (timeWait == std::chrono::milliseconds(0)) {
    // note that our refactored `wait_for` will not contain this branch
    cv.wait(ulock, waitCondition);
} else {
    // note that our refactored `wait` will not contain this branch
    bool timedOut = !cv.wait_for(ulock, timeWait, waitCondition);
    if (timedOut) ++count;
}
```

That `++count` smells like a race condition to me. Sure, we're operating under the mutex lock *here*; but I suspect it's possible that some other thread might have observed the decremented value of `count` and acted on it, which might mean that here we're bumping `count` from 0 to 1, or from `maxThreads` to `maxThreads+1`. I'm not sure that this can happen, but I would look at this codepath *very* closely if I were you.

---

Consider what happens in code like

```
Thread A         Thread B         Thread C

Barrier b(2);
b.wait();        b.wait();
                 <notifyAll>
                 b.wait();        b.wait();
                                  <notifyAll>
                 <awaken>
<awaken>
<resume waiting>
```

If I understand correctly, when thread A finally gets scheduled and belatedly awakens from its `cv.wait`, it will observe `gen == generation` because `generation` has been toggled *twice* since it went to sleep. So it will remain blocked, even though it should have become unblocked as a result of thread B's first `b.wait()`.

I'm not sure how to fix this, but it might involve thread B being forced to block, *itself*, until all the other threads in the current phase have indicated that they're unblocked. In fact I'm not sure that *that* would even fix the issue.

---

It's worth mentioning that it is physically possible for the programmer to destroy a `Barrier` while some other thread is still blocked waiting on it. Presumably you're okay with having this be undefined behavior.